# as3 Greensock throwProps Error loading Children

Tags: actionscript-3, loading, children, gsap

I am having an issue with Greensock display children of a movieClip. I know there error is in these lines

```
// this works and makes flagButton alpha to .3
// Displays Flags which are children in the button called FlagButton
flagButton.alpha = .3; // works

 addChild(mc);
// But if I uncomment this code the flags in my MC are GONE. It doesnt make sense. 
/// The MC shows and I can control it via greensock but FLAGS are gone. 
//mc.addChild(flagButton);
```

What would be causing this? Its an issue with children and display I think.

Here is the full code:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([ThrowPropsPlugin]);

var folderLanguages:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("Languages");

var availLang:Array = folderLanguages.getDirectoryListing();
var Lang:Array;
var LangPath:Array;
var flagButton:MovieClip;

var myFlagInfo:LoaderInfo;
var myFlag:Loader;


function getLang(evt:Event)
{
Lang = new Array();
LangPath = new Array();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < availLang.length; i++)
   {

   if(availLang[i].isDirectory)
         {
        //trace(availLang[i].name);// gets the name
        Lang.push(availLang[i].name);
        LangPath.push(availLang[i].nativePath);
        trace(availLang[i].nativePath);// gets the name

         }
   }
   evt.target.visible = false;
}

var Language:MovieClip;
var LangButton:MovieClip;
var flag:Loader;
var fh:Object; 

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var bounds:Rectangle;;

//setupTextField(mc, bounds);
var blitMask:BlitMask;

bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var t1:uint, t2:uint, y1:Number, y2:Number, yOverlap:Number, yOffset:Number;

function displayFlags(evt:Event = null)
{
    if(!Lang) { return; }
    flagButton = new MovieClip();
    addChild(flagButton);

    //addChild(mc);
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < Lang.length; i++)
   {
       //Language = new MovieClip();
       //Language.name = Lang[i];
       LangButton = new button01();
       LangButton.name = Lang[i];
       LangButton.btext.text = Lang[i];
       LangButton.y = LangButton.height * i;
       LangButton.btext.x = 125;
       addChild(LangButton);
       flag = new Loader();
       flag.load(new URLRequest(LangPath[i]+"/flag.png"));
       flag.name = Lang[i];
       flag.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedFlag);
       function loadedFlag(evt:Event)
       {

            var fh = flag.getBounds(flag);

           trace("FLAG HEIGHT = " + fh);
           trace("flag Name: "+ flag.name);
           trace(flag);
           myFlagInfo = evt.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
           myFlag= myFlagInfo.loader;
           myFlag.y = (LangButton.height/2) - (flag.height/2);


       } 
       LangButton.addChild(flag);
       flagButton.addChild(LangButton);


   }


evt.target.visible = false;
flagButton.alpha = .3;
addChild(mc);
//mc.addChild(flagButton);

//bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
blitMask = new BlitMask(mc, bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height, false);      
blitMask.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
}







function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.killTweensOf(mc);
    y1 = y2 = mc.y;
    yOffset = this.mouseY - mc.y;
    yOverlap = Math.max(0, mc.height - bounds.height);
    t1 = t2 = getTimer();
    mc.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    mc.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var y:Number = this.mouseY - yOffset;
    //if mc's position exceeds the bounds, make it drag only half as far with each mouse movement (like iPhone/iPad behavior)
    if (y > bounds.top) {
        mc.y = (y + bounds.top) * 0.5;
    } else if (y < bounds.top - yOverlap) {
        mc.y = (y + bounds.top - yOverlap) * 0.5;
    } else {
        mc.y = y;
    }
    blitMask.update();
    var t:uint = getTimer();
    //if the frame rate is too high, we won't be able to track the velocity as well, so only update the values 20 times per second
    if (t - t2 > 50) {
        y2 = y1;
        t2 = t1;
        y1 = mc.y;
        t1 = t;
    }
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    mc.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
    mc.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    var time:Number = (getTimer() - t2) / 1000;
    var yVelocity:Number = (mc.y - y2) / time;
    ThrowPropsPlugin.to(mc, {throwProps:{
                                 y:{velocity:yVelocity, max:bounds.top, min:bounds.top - yOverlap, resistance:300}
                             }, onUpdate:blitMask.update, ease:Strong.easeOut
                            }, 10, 0.3, 1);
}




B1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getLang);
B2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayFlags);
```

Comment: when you say they're GONE what do you mean? Null object? Can't you see them? Have you trace it's coordinates?

Comment: Here is a link to the zip of my project without the greensock plugin. I need to somehow get throwprops connected to flagButton. http://www.massmediamail.com/testing/GreenscokRocks.zip